# How to Customize ListView in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

HI..

i am new to QT,i want to know how to customize the listview in QT i.e i want to add multiple icon in single row.. etc.. i tried lot i am not getting how to do that..

i tried with Qlistwidget, in tat i can only insert single row with one image.. i am not able to place multiple icon with desired locations..

please assist me, which control is good listview or listwidget.
and how to customize the same according to my view

if you have any sample examples. please provide me the link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a delegate to customize the rendering of the items in your view.

From the [model/view programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) docs: delegates [are responsible for rendering individual items](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) in the views.

See the [pixelator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-pixelator-example.html) sample for example usage.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at QTableView or QTableWidget. You can insert the icons in the first two columns and the text in the third column. Or any other way you like it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use some delegates.
Have a look at http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/model-view-delegate.html

Hope it helps !